# My dockerignore file is not saving anything

Tags: docker, dockerignore

I have a .dockerignore file and I want to exclude node module **node_modules**.

Whatever I type in the file and I save, it does not save.

What could be the issue?

Comment: You might want to include your .dockerignore file here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like you have to set proper chmod and chown for this file and add it to repository via `git commit`.
2. Check official docs at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: I am not pushing the code to the repo. Everything is local.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is still not saving through vs code. So finally what I have done is, I have open it in another editor and then I was able to save it.